# Strongly typed enum as union in rust: How to determine type of value and retrieve it; How to do "constructors"

Tags: types, enums, constructor, rust

typed community,
Coming from C++ I'm looking for a solution to store values of different types in a struct in Rust.
The overall idea is to have a priority queue stored in a Hashmap and index by name of the queue, allowing to add entries and sorted by timestamp. Those entries should be able to hold a value field of a previously defined type.
The use case is to be able to version control the value and annotate the value through additional fields if required.

In C++ I would do that via inheritance from a defined interface and a list which stores pointers to that struct, or through a void pointer and type indicating enum field.

So far I found out that Rust uses a typed enum for that. My problem is how "typecasting" works (and as I understand there might actually be a different paradigm in Rust than in C++ in terms of memory safety, since the ways I would do it in C++ would require RTTI or type-casting).
What would be the proper way to do this in Rust?

Example:

```
enum Value {
    Int(i64),
    Float(f64),
    Str(String),
}

struct Entry {
    timestamp:i64,
    value: Value,
}

struct VersionList {
    name: String,
    entries: LinkedList<Entry>
}
```

The question now is what is the paradigm in Rust to extract the value of the list if the type of the value is not known.
One way is to create one method for each value type and have a match expression in there, returning the value with the correct type if it matches, or otherwise returning None. However, this means that always all methods would need to be called until one of them does return an actual value instead of None, which produces a lot of code.

Example:

```
impl Entry {
pub fn get_i64(&self) -> Option<i64> {
    match &self.value {
        Value::Int(i) => Some(*i),
            _ => None
    }
}
```

Also, I realized that Rust has no notion of constructors. So to create the value I created a function to write to the correct field. Is there a different way of doing this in Rust?

```
impl Entry {

    fn new_int(value: i64, timestamp: i64, user_id: String) -> Entry {
        //pub fn new(value: i64, timestamp: i64, user_id: String) -> Property {
        Entry {
            timestamp: timestamp,
            value: Value::Int(value),
        }
    }

    fn new_str(value: String, timestamp: i64, user_id: String) -> Entry {
        Entry {
            timestamp: timestamp,
            value: Value::Str(value),
        }
    }
...
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *to extract the value of the list if the type of the value is not known* And what are you going to do with it, if you don't know the type?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. So if in C++, do you know the type before you cast the value? If so, you still need code like `if (type == "i64") {do_i64_op();} else if (type == "f64") {do_f64_op();} else {do_else()}`, so you can def a rust function like `impl Entry { fn get_value(&self) -> Value {self.value}}`, and when you use it, you do `match value { ... } `

Answer (score 2):

Don't think in terms of `get/set` methods (which would be a bad idea in C++ too btw). Instead, manipulate the `enum` directly, which allows you to extract the type and value in a single step:

```
match entry.value {
   Value::Int (i)   => process_int_value (i),
   Value::Float (f) => process_float_value (f),
   Value::Str (s)   => process_string_value (s),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like @Jmb's answer and my comment, I didn't quite sure why you need to do typecasting.

But in case you need some common operation on all data types I would suggest to create a trait (which should be an alternative to C++ interface).

```rust
use std::collections::LinkedList;
use std::fmt::Display;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Value<T> {
    timestamp:i64,
    value: T,
}

trait Entry {
    fn print_out(&self);
    fn get_timestamp(&self) -> i64;
}

impl<T: Display> Entry for Value<T> {
    fn print_out(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.value);
    }

    fn get_timestamp(&self) -> i64 {
        self.timestamp
    }
}

struct VersionList {
    name: String,
    entries: LinkedList<Box<dyn Entry>>
}

impl VersionList {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        VersionList { name: "test".to_owned(), entries: LinkedList::<Box<dyn Entry>>::new() }
    }

    pub fn put<T: Display + 'static>(&mut self, value: Value<T>) {
        self.entries.push_back(Box::new(value));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = VersionList::new();
    list.put(Value {timestamp: 3, value: "abc".to_owned()});
    list.put(Value {timestamp: 1, value: 1});
    list.put(Value {timestamp: 2, value: 1.5});
    let iter = list.entries.iter();
    for ent in iter {
        ent.print_out();
    }

    println!("{}", "=".repeat(80));

    let mut vec = list.entries.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    vec.sort_by(|a, b| a.get_timestamp().cmp(&b.get_timestamp()));
    for ent in vec.iter() {
        ent.print_out();
    }
}
```